# Why can't jmeter parse the hash characters?

Tags: java, groovy, hash, jmeter, character

```
${result} // return hash character   a12df45657dkkd........

log.info("result" + ${result});
```

I

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScrptEngineImpl.$() is applicable for argument types: ...
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), get(java.lang.String), any(groovy.lang.Closure), tap(groovy.lang.Closure)......
```

Why can't jmeter parse the hash characters?

Comment: How did you set `result` value?

Answer (score 0):

The dollar curly `${ }` syntax is to be used within groovy strings:

```
def foo = "bar"
println "I am a string and this is a value ${foo}"
```

(would print `I am a string and this is a value bar`)

if you want the value of the `result` variable in normal code (outside of a string), you can just use the value as is:

```
println(someMethod())
def someMethod() {
  def result = System.currentTimeMillis()
  result // returns result, no curlies needed
}
```

(would print the current time in milliseconds)

As for your code, we would need more context to answer your question in more detail. Like the comments mention, we would need to see what method/part of code you are in, where and how the `result` variable is set etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts because:

1. It conflicts with Groovy [GString templates](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine)
2. [JMeter caches the first occurrence of the variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) so on next iteration(s) you will get the value from the first iteration

So if you want to print a variable value to the log file you should use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
log.info("result" + vars.get("result"));
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)